# VS 2013 Wpf visual bug?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

After reading some stuff on the internet I decided to try switch from C#+Windows forms to C#+WPF. But I ran into some weird stuff (bug? invalid installation?): in editor everything looks fine and nice, but when I build it - it looks noticeably different from what I see in editor (for example: even though I set borders thickness to 0 - they are still present and ignore this setting overall).

Any way to fix it?

Here is code I'm using (I'm not using anything specific, just some menus and buttons).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Window.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality"/>
</Window.Effect>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Generate new"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Export"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Import"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="E_xit"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Test"/>
        </Menu>
        <Grid>    
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="352,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <GroupBox Header="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="110" Width="123"/>

        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is capture to help better understand question.
[image]

Comment: Don't assume a bug anywhere but in *your* code or expectactions.

Comment: For the 2 people using the "unclear what you are asking", might be better to use the new off-topic reason. Not a big deal though, it still covers.

Comment: Added code and link and screen cap.

Comment: Define your Grid Rows and Columns, or use a DockPanel for that effect.

Comment: `I set borders thickness to 0` - There's not a single reference to `BorderThickness` in your XAML. Please explain your problem properly. BTW, don't use the Visual Studio designer in WPF. Learn XAML like a man.

Comment: Alright, I think I forgot to set that for this example.
`ResizeMode="CanMinimize" BorderThickness="0"`
Added that to `<Window>`, still no effect.

Comment: @user3735111 you can't set the border thickness of a `Window` like that, because that's determined by the operating system theme. If you want to create a custom-looking Window, then create a new Window Template. See [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably built your window by using what you learned with Forms: you dragged and dropped controls. This will result in suboptimal results in WPF. WPF has a system of positioning elements that way more advanced than pixel positioning.

You should have a look into tutorials about WPF layout. WPF is a way different beast than WinForms and if you approach it as "WinForms with a funny look" it will not work well.

Look into WPF layout, container controls and relative positioning. If you see any absolute values in your XAML, it's probably not perfect.

Example:

```
Margin="432,289,0,0"
```

That's bad. It's absolute positioning. It does not care how large the window is or how large the borders are. The control is placed 432/289 from the upper left. That's what you see. The distance from the upper left is kept, but as your window is influenced by your windows style, it looks not like your want it to look.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I'm in process of learning at the moment, so I'm playing around with DockPanel and other stuff. But the point is that I don't get what I see in editor on the output (I outlined problematic spots on pic - header and whole border are obvious, but it also screws up button positioning as well (later on I made it unresizable, and buttons are just sitting exactly on top of border, even though I have a gap in editor).

Comment: The ouput is your input, influenced by the style set by the operating system. This is not visible in the editor, mostly because that would only be the style of your development system. Your users may have a totally different style. Learn WPF the WPF way, that means your aplication will be style agnostic.